# Intercept magic method calls in python class

Tags: python, class, proxy

I am trying to make a class that wraps a value that will be used across multiple other objects. For computational reasons, the aim is for this wrapped value to only be calculated once and the reference to the value passed around to its users. I don't believe this is possible in vanilla python due to its object container model. Instead, my approach is a wrapper class that is passed around, defined as follows:

```
class DynamicProperty():

    def __init__(self, value = None):
        # Value of the property
        self.value: Any = value

    def __repr__(self):
        # Use value's repr instead
        return repr(self.value)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # Doesn't exist in wrapper, get it from the value 
        # instead
        return getattr(self.value, attr)
```

The following works as expected:

```
wrappedString = DynamicProperty("foo")
wrappedString.upper()  # 'FOO'

wrappedFloat = DynamicProperty(1.5)
wrappedFloat.__add__(2)  # 3.5
```

However, implicitly calling `__add__` through normal syntax fails:

```
wrappedFloat + 2  # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for 
                  # +: 'DynamicProperty' and 'float'
```

Is there a way to intercept these implicit method calls without explicitly defining magic methods for DynamicProperty to call the method on its `value` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talking about "passing by reference" will only confuse you. Keep that terminology to languages where you can have a choice on that, and where it makes a difference. In Python you always pass *objects* around - and this passing is the equivalent of "passing by reference" - for *all* objects - from None to int to a live asyncio network connection pool instance.

With that out of the way: the algorithm the language follows to retrieve attributes from an object is complicated, have details - implementing `__getattr__` is just the tip of the iceberg. Reading the document called "[Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)" in its entirety will give you a better grasp of all the mechanisms involved in retrieving attributes.

That said, here is how it works for "magic" or "dunder" methods - (special functions with two underscores before and two after the name): when you use an operator that requires the existence of the method that implements it (like `__add__` for `+`), the language checks the *class*  of your object for the `__add__` method - not the instance. And `__getattr__` on the class can dynamically create attributes for instances of that class only. 
But that is not the only problem: you could create a metaclass (inheriting from `type`) and put a `__getattr__` method on this metaclass. For all querying you would do from Python, it would look like your object had the  `__add__` (or any other dunder method) in its class. However, for dunder methods, Python do not go through the normal attribute lookup mechanism - it "looks" directly at the class, if the dunder method is "physically" there. There are slots in the memory structure that holds the classes for each of the possible dunder methods - and they either refer to the corresponding method, or are "null" (this is "viewable" when coding in C on the Python side, the default `dir` will show these methods when they exist, or omit them if not). If they are not there, Python will just "say" the object does not implement that operation and period.

The way to work around that with a proxy object like you want is to create  a proxy class that either features the dunder methods from the class you want to wrap, or features all possible methods, and upon being called, check if the underlying object actually implements the called method.

That is why "serious" code will rarely, if ever, offer true "transparent" proxy objects. There are exceptions, but from "Weakrefs", to "super()", to concurrent.futures, just to mention a few in the core language and stdlib, no one attempts a "fully working transparent proxy" - instead, the api is more like you call a ".value()" or ".result()"  method on the wrapper to get to the original object itself.

However, it *can* be done, as I described above. I even have a small (long unmaintained) package on pypi that does that, wrapping a proxy for a future.
The code is at  https://bitbucket.org/jsbueno/lelo/src/master/lelo/_lelo.py

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, that's exactly the information I was looking for. I'll take your advice of avoiding proxy objects under consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator in your case does not work, because `DynamicProperty` does not inherit from `float`. See:

```
>>> class Foo(float):
    pass

>>> Foo(1.5) + 2
3.5
```

So, you'll need to do some kind of dynamic inheritance:

```
def get_dynamic_property(instance):

    base = type(instance)

    class DynamicProperty(base):
        pass

    return DynamicProperty(instance)


wrapped_string = get_dynamic_property("foo")
print(wrapped_string.upper())

wrapped_float = get_dynamic_property(1.5)
print(wrapped_float + 2)
```

Output:

```
FOO
3.5
```

Comment: While you can subclass whatever you want to wrap, it doesn't necessarily allow you to pass by reference. For example, I can't create an instance of `class FloatWrapper(int): ...`, pass its reference, and change an instance value such that all original references now point to the updated value.